# Rails 3- Understanding the Controller/Routes relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

which allows me to load URLs like

- /photos
- /photos/2
- /photos/2/edit

Edit allows the user to change the image, but I want a different kind of edit for permission type stuff specific to the app I'm building, which would look like:

- /photos/2/updatesettings

So in the photos controller I added "def updatesettings ...."

And in the routes I added:

```
resources :photos do
 collection do
    get 'updatesettings'
 end
end
```

But I'm getting an error: "Routing Error No route matches"

Suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your routes file will match the url '/photos/updatesettings'

The only way I know how to do what you want to do is:

```
match "photos/:id/updatesettings" => "photos#updatesettings"
```

In the second part of that line, photos is telling it to look in the photos controller, and #updatesettings is telling it the method to call.

You would put this outside of resources :photos, so your code would be

```
resources :photos
match "photos/:id/updatesettings" => "photos#updatesettings"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a high chance you're using a form to update these settings, am I right?*

In which case you want to do `post 'updatesettings'` in your routes file, not `get`. This will define a route that responds to `POST` requests, vs one that only responds to `GET` requests. If you want both then use a `get` and a `post` line in your routes file.

* Most of the time, yes I am.

Comment: Well I need a ShowSettings to render an HTML page showing all the settings... Then I guess I'll need an updatesettings to Post to ?

Comment: I do have a permissions table that handles all this stuff. Maybe this belongs in that controller...